# AWS Amplify and NEXT JS environment Variables

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to use the AWS amplify environment variables with my Next JS deployment but it doesn't seem to be reading them at all. They seem to be loaded from the env.local file and not Amplify.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to redeploy?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to use environment variables in the backend/API routes, then you can edit the build pipeline in Amplify to pass the environment variables in the build command. This lets NodeJS and Next see them.

See the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-environment-variables.html

At time of writing it looks like:

```
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e DB_HOST -e DB_USER -e DB_PASS >> .env.production
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
```

NEXT_PUBLIC_* variable will go to the frontend, so don't prefix anything sensitive with NEXT_PUBLIC_.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue. After changing the environment variables in AWS Amplify you need to deploy the project again, and you do not need to change anything in the `amplify.yml` (build settings).